# Dot product equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-analysis

I saw in my textbook solutions that one can write $\underline m \cdot \underline r$ as $\underline m\:\underline r$ . Is this valid ?

Where $\underline m$ is a constant vector, $\underline r$ is the position vector and r is the magnitude of the position vector

Leading on from that, I want to know if $(r^2\underline m)=(r^2\cdot\underline m)$

Pls help. Thanks

Comment: You can do whatever you want but I've never seen this notation before.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, I changed the syntax to make it more understandable.